# Best way to read Beacon Manufacture Data in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am trying to Read Beacon(BLE Device) manufacture Data which is in below image 
[image]

And I am getting response as,
[image]

and my code is,

```
id manufactureData = [advertisementData objectOrNilForKey:@"kCBAdvDataManufacturerData"];
        if ([manufactureData isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) {
            int8_t measuredPower = 0;
            NSUInteger dataLength = [manufactureData length];
            for (int i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
                NSRange powerRange = NSMakeRange(i, 1);
                [manufactureData getBytes:&measuredPower range:powerRange];
                NSLog(@"index :%@ info :%hhd", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i+1],measuredPower);
            }
        }
```

Is this is correct way to read the manufacture data, Here i am trying to read Battery Address value. which i have to show.

Comment: i am also getting like this codes only in kCBAdvDataManufacturerData = <ffff0215 e84a40af 7b8de88d 4a7b40af afe84a40 40af7b8d c3>; ... so how to fetch data from it ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a correct way of reading through the returned `NSData`.

Given this, your information is returning 32 for battery value, does that seem correct?

If not, can you find out if your manufacturer device is little endian or big endian? [Link to explanation here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) if you do not know what that means.

The short version of the endianness question is if your info is coming from a big endian processor then your `NSData` will be backwards. making your battery value 77

One quick note: This does not sound like an iBeacon implementation. iBeacons are NOT the same as BLE enabled devices. This is most likely a BLE enabled device and not an iBeacon.

Comment: thanks for response.! ya it is not a ibeacon. it is a Beacon, but in android we able to retrieve data as by doing this (scanData[maxLength-1] & 0x0f) * 10 + (scanData[maxLength] & 0x0f);

Comment: And I assume the values you are receiving on your android device are different than your iOS device?

Comment: In Android Beacon Giving us data length as 30, manually we are reading block by block bytes by comparing with address.

Comment: I'm unsure if you are reading the data correctly on an Android device, but looking at the information you gave for 'kCBAdvDataManufacturerData' in your screenshot, and how you are reading it on the Obj-C side. That is valid. Do you know whether or not your endianness is big or little on the device? What are you expecting the temperature value be in the information you provided? (Do you actually know what your temp value is so we can confirm when you are finding it correctly)